# Can I set the content of a View to an XML file?

Tags: android, kotlin, view

I want to make a custom View for which I already have an XML layout file, but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

`setContentView()` doesn't exist in classes not derived from Activity, and I don't know how to render a view inflated with a `LayoutInflater`.

My view is based on a `RelativeLayout`, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom `View` class extending `RelativeLayout`:

```
class CustomRelativeLayout(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet
) : RelativeLayout(context, attrs) 
{
    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.your_layout, this)
    }
}
```

Then just use it with:

```
<CustomRelativeLayout></CustomRelativeLayout>
```

in your XML files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the static `View.inflate()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#inflate(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) and pass your `RelativeLayout` as the third parameter.

```
val relative = /* your RelativeLayout here */
View.inflate(context, R.layout.your_layout_file, relative)
```

Unlike `setContentView()`, this won't remove any existing children of the RelativeLayout. So you may want to call this first:

```
relative.removeAllViews()
```